# Trying to select a random number from the length of an array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an issue in which i am trying to select a random number using an arrays length as the parameter.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
var r = Math.floor(Math.random(myArray.length));
```

That is what i have so far, if my array is size 7 for example i would like r to be a random number up to 7.

So far it return r as 0, even when testing in the browser console

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Math.random()` function does not pay attention to parameters; it always returns a random value in `[0, 1)`.  Thus to get a random *integer* between 0 and some upper limit, you'd use

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
```

Comment: @NickDewitt note that the indexes of a JavaScript array run from 0 up to `length - 1`.

Comment: But `Math.random()` never returns 1. (That's what the notation `[0, 1)` means.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions guys, still having a bit of trouble with that, i tried in the console and it only returns 1 for some reason?

Comment: @GrandeurH well it's hard to say because you posted very little of your code. The `Math.random()` function definitely returns values between 0 and 1, and multiplication works fine in JavaScript.

Comment: I added in the array in which i am using if that helps

Comment: @GrandeurH if you use the code in this answer (*not* your posted code), the value of `r` will range from 0 through 4, which is correct because your array has 5 elements.

Comment: Apologies it does work , thanks for the answer!

Comment: @NickDewitt: If `.length === 5`, `Math.random() * 5` will be `[0, 5)`. Flooring that will give you a random value out of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.